# PHP won't update MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've done some research into some other people's problems on here, but I can't quite see what's going wrong. I'm trying to update my form which already has the current user (who is logged in)'s data, but I want them to be able to update their profile.

This is what my code looks like:

```
  <?php
      // Retreive db data
    $me = $_SESSION['username'];
    require('db.php');

    $data = "SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username='$me'";

    $query = mysql_query($data);
    $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);



    // Updating
    $Username=$data2['username'] ;
    $Email= $data2['email'] ;

    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
    $username_save = mysql_real_scape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email_save = mysql_real_scape_string($_POST['email']);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username ='$username_save', email ='$email_save' WHERE username = '$me'")
    or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Saved!";

    }
       ?>




       <form role="form">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="username">Username: </label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username_save" value="<?php echo $data2['username']?>">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="pwd">Email Address: </label>
           <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_save" value="<?php echo $data2['email']?>">
         </div>
         <button input type="Submit" name="save" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
          <button input type="Sumbit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </form>
```

When I submit my new values (the echo values works fine) and press submit (username=danielleeee email=test@danielle.com), my url looks like this:

> pages/admin/edit.php?username_save=danielleeee&email_save=test%40danielle.com&save=

If anyone could shed some light on this for me that would be fantastic!
Thank you.

Comment: $_POST method is not defined; so learn how to use $_POST; because you form works with $_GET method and your vars are in $_GET superglobal

Comment: Stop using `mysql_` functions, they have been deprecated for a long time now. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead. You are also vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form>` defaults to a GET method if not explicitly implied `<form role="form">`.

So, => `<form role="form" method="post">`

since you're using POST arrays.

Strangely enough, error reporting would not have thrown you anything about it neither.

- I learned that lesson the hard way once, *"once"*.

Also, make sure you started the session since you are using sessions.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Yet, error reporting *would* have caught *that one* if it wasn't started and would have thrown you something about it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

However, `name="username_save"` and `name="email_save"` those are not the same as your POST arrays here.

- `$_POST['username']` => `$_POST['username_save']`
- `$_POST['email']` => `$_POST['email_save']`

Those need to match and error reporting would have thrown you undefined index notices.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

It's best to use a conditional `!empty()` for your POST arrays. The `!` is the "NOT" operator in PHP.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

and will ensure that no empty values are being passed.

I.e.:

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{

if(!empty($_POST['username_save']) && !empty($_POST['email_save']) ){
$username_save = mysql_real_scape_string($_POST['username_save']);
$email_save = mysql_real_scape_string($_POST['email_save']);

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username ='$username_save', email ='$email_save' 
             WHERE username = '$me'")
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Saved!";

}

}
```

Sidenote: You can replace `&&` (AND) for an `||` (OR) depending on the condition you wish to use.

---

Plus, as stated. The MySQL_ API will be removed from future PHP versions. It's best to move on to either the MySQLi or PDO API and with a prepared statement.

References:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Thanks! That worked great (will mark as correct but I have to wait 3 minutes apparently). Only problem I'm getting now is that 'username' and 'email' are coming up as undefined index?

Comment: @dplatt You're welcome. Reload my answer, I've made an edit about that as I kept looking at your code.